# Assigning same values to 2 pointers, not equalising their references (pointers in C)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, assign

```
    printf("%p\n\n", element);       //0x1000020c0
    table->head->element = element;
    printf("%p\n\n", table->head->element);   //0x1000020c0
```

I have a pointer to a struct which points to another struct where is char* variable is stored. The problem is a pointer(char * element) which is sent to this method is modified somewhere else, and I don't want those modifications to be affected in table->head->element.  Simply said I want to make their values equal, not the reference.

I knew that we can assign same values to 2 pointers like this: *p1=*p2. However, I am not sure how to do that with structs, I tried:

```
    *(table->head->element) = *element;
```

But it did not work.

I hope I could clarify my question.

Comment: `*table->head->element = *element;`?

Comment: By did not work I mean that I am getting EXC_BAD_ ACCESS(code=1;...)

Comment: that looks like you haven't allocated space for at least one of the pointers

Comment: Seems that is right. Just checked through the debugger. It does not allocate memory for element in struct head. However, I have this line         table->head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); , which I though should have allocated memory.

Comment: if you have a struct with a pointer in it, allocating space for the struct allocates space for the pointer itself, but not for pointed-to data.  The compiler can't know when you want to allocate space after all.

Comment: Right, I got it. Thanks for pointing out. You can add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the pointed-to string by a copy, not simply a reference, you'll need to strcpy() it into some new memory. e.g.

```
int len = strlen(element);
table->head->element = malloc(len+1); // +1 for string-terminating null
strcpy(table->head->element, element);
```

(or use strdup() for a one-line solution, as pointed out in R Sahu's reply).

Comment: That will work, but I don't want using additional coping, because we can do it with pointers

Comment: @Fiz, you can't have both -- keep pointer and expect the value to stay independent.

Comment: @rSahu would you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: If you have ten pointers 1..10 all pointing to the same memory, and some code through pointer 1 changes the memory, all the pointers will see the change. They're all pointing at the same thing. You change the thing, they're still all pointing at the now-changed thing. If you want different pointers pointing at different things now, then you'll have to create/allocate a new thing.

Comment: @GrahamPerks that is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @Fiz Graham's solution avoids that. Writing `*p = *q;` **is** copying, just like `strcpy`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb while that's true for structs (the entire struct will be copied), if p & q are char* (and OP says he has a char*), only the first character will be copied. Hence the need for strcpy, to copy the entire string. (I feel we may need a more concrete example, perhaps we are talking different topics here rather than actually disagreeing).

Comment: @GrahamPerks I'm agreeing with you and trying to counter Fiz's objection that copying is required to do a copy

Answer (score 0):

Responding to OP's comments in the answer by @GrahamPerks.

> That will work, but I don't want using additional coping, because we can do it with pointer

Let's say the memory used by `element` looks like below:

```
element +---------+       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
        |  ptr1   |  ->   | a |   | s | t | r | i | n | g | '\0' |
        +---------+       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

If you use:

```
table->head->element = element;
```

the value of `table->head->element` is `ptr1`.

If some time later, you went ahead and changed the contents of `ptr1` through `element`, such as by using:

```
fscanf(file, "%s", element);
```

You could end up with:

```
element +---------+       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
        |  ptr1   |  ->   | n | e | w |   | s | t | r | i | n | g | '\0' |
        +---------+       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

At that point, the string that you see from `table->head->element` is `"new string"`, not `"a string"`.

This is what happens when you don't copy the contents of `element` but just copy the pointer value of `element`.

If you want the value of `table->head->element` to remain `"a string"` while the value of `element` changes, you have to copy the contents of `element` using

```
int len = strlen(element);
table->head->element = malloc(len+1);
strcpy(table->head->element, element);
```

or, if your complier supports `strdup`, by using

```
table->head->element = strdup(element);
```

Comment: OMG, thanks for the strdup() reminder! Been out of C for too long. malloc & strcpy, silly me!

Comment: @GrahamPerks malloc and strcpy are Standard C functions whereas strdup is not, so your code is quite fine !